Active rhapsody application object returns null with rhaspsody 9.0.1 plugin development
We recently migrated to Rhapsody 9.0.1, a 64-bit installation from Rhapsody 8.1.2 (32-bit Installation).
While migrating our Plugins we are facing an issue.
Even when the Rhapsody 9.0.1 instance is opened "RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication();" returns null.
When we are running the plugin with all the Rhapsody 9 dependencies, we are still getting the Error:
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.1.2\Share\JavaAPI\rhapsody.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication()Lcom/telelogic/rhapsody/core/IRPApplication;
 

With Rhapsody 8 the plugin was working fine but having the issue with Rhapsody 9.
We updated the Registry with Rhapsody 9.0.1 installation location as well
Rhapsody 9 Installation Location: C:\Program Files\IBM\Rhapsody\9.0.1
